# Missing follower

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So my follower, Stenvar, in Skyrim got lost and I can't find him anywhere.

I have tried to use a console command to get to him. What I did was pressing `` ` `` key to open up the console and all that I achieved was
some stuff like `Compiled script not saved!` or `item 000b998c not found for parameter ObjectReferenceID`.

Here is what I'm typing:

```
prid 000b988c moveto player
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suppose you know how to open the console ... ( tilde key, beside the 1 )

"help follower 3" will display follower global variables

At this point PlayerFollowerCount = 1.00

"set playerfollowercount to 0" will remove any follower you currently have, but i'm not sure what happens to them ?! Still, you'll be able to take another follower to come with you.

Hope this helps

Comment: Well i cant recruit any other follower so thats why.

Comment: Read the answer it should help